# Use more than one source to slide toggle an element

Tags: jquery

I've got a full screen slide down navigation menu with links which when clicked scroll to the relevant section . The menu is slide toggled by clicking on the #hamburger div . what i want is for the menu to slide out of view again when i click on a link but what happens is it slides up and then back down again

```
<div id="hamburger">
    <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a></a></li>
            <li><a></a></li>
            <li><a></a></li>
        </ul>            
    </nav>
</div> 

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hamburger , ul li a").click(function(){
        $("#navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the *`event-propagation`*,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hamburger , ul li a").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

When you are clicking over the *`anchor`* elements, the event will be propagated to the top until it reaches the document and during that time it crosses the `#hamburger` and it will also fire its click event. Hence the `#navigation` element is sliding up and down.

Comment: resolved it by moving the nav but your explanation has given me more understanding of what was happening

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that my nav was inside the hamburger div . moving it to below the hamburger div has done the trick . rookie mistake